# C++ Class initialization within another class, getting error

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

I'm from a java background and I'm trying to learn C++ with QT trying to make a tic tac toe game. I have problems with initializing objects within a certain class : I want the MainWindow class to have a Player instance and initialize Player by calling it's constructor but I don't understand the errors

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include "board.h"
#include <qstring.h>
class Player
{
public:
    QString token;
    Player(QString);
    void jouerCoup(int,int, Board&);
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

And this is the MainWindow class

```
#include <qstring.h>
#include "player.h"
#include "board.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    Player aPlayer;
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
private slots:
     void buttonHandle();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

In MainWindow.cpp I try this

```
aPLayer = new Player("X");
```

and I get this error :

```
../tictactoe/mainwindow.cpp: In constructor 'MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget*)':
../tictactoe/mainwindow.cpp:6:26: error: no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'
 ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
```

I tried making the QString mutable, I have also a constructor in Player.cpp that takes a QString and assign it to the Player's member.

Any indication as to what I should do next ? Can I initialize Player in the MainWindow definition directly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be that you declare your aPlayer member variable as being a Player object, however you initialize it as if it is a pointer to Player object. You should either declare it as a pointer:

```
Player *aPlayer;
```

or in the MainWindow class contructor initialize it as:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        aPlayer("X")
{}
```